# Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state. Also unable to find products with no SKU

Tags: error, magento2.4.1

```
Magento 2.4.1
```

I've done a Migration from Magento 1.9.4.0 to 2.4.1. There is a total of 1750 products.

I went to:

- Catalog --) Products, select 200 per page and was browsing by using the right arrow. It takes longer than expected for the next page of products to load and then when going from page 6 to page 7 of products (out of 9 total) - out of nowhere - there is a pop-up which says:

> Attention Something went wrong.

If you click OK - you get the following Error on the page itself:

> Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have
> restored the filter to its original state.

When this happens, that specific user is corrupted somehow and you always get this Error when going into products.

I tried deleting all Cache and re-indexing but it doesn't help nor does logging out and logging back in.

I found articles where they suspect not having SKUs on products may cause this and adding SKUs to those products might fix it. When searching for products with NO SKUs via SQL however, I always get the following Error:

#1146 - Table 'database_name741.catalog_product_entity' does not exist.

I am not that good with running SQL queries so I was just copying and pasting some from this article here:

https://gist.github.com/tegansnyder/8464261

**Any idea what I can do to identify products with no SKU or how else to fix this problem?**

---

Updated later on January 21st, 2021:

The issue with the Error message was resolved by going to the *catalog_product_entity* table in the database, ordering it so that the products with no SKU would come up first and then editing those products right in the database (**adding SKU numbers**).

**The Error is gone now but everything is still very slow in the Admin panel. SLOW QUERY Log is enabled on the server and this is the output for today:**

```
SET timestamp=1611145227;
DELETE FROM `mg_core_session` WHERE (session_expires < 1611145219);
# Time: 2021-01-21T00:30:30.299753Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 14835
# Query_time: 3.114757  Lock_time: 0.000068 Rows_sent: 51210  Rows_examined: 51210
use denverpl_mage752;
SET timestamp=1611189030;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mg1v_session`;
# Time: 2021-01-21T01:35:35.096267Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 16041
# Query_time: 3.318408  Lock_time: 0.000104 Rows_sent: 283212  Rows_examined: 283212
use herbbask_mage277;
SET timestamp=1611192935;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mgo0_sales_flat_quote_address`;
# Time: 2021-01-21T02:50:48.373411Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 17393
# Query_time: 3.720180  Lock_time: 0.000085 Rows_sent: 876910  Rows_examined: 876910
use orchidaf_g1;
SET timestamp=1611197448;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mg_core_url_rewrite`;
# Time: 2021-01-21T02:51:00.897375Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 17397
# Query_time: 5.252664  Lock_time: 0.000091 Rows_sent: 3380000  Rows_examined: 3380000
use orchidaf_flower;
SET timestamp=1611197460;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mg_amasty_geoip_block`;
# Time: 2021-01-21T02:51:46.297531Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 17397
# Query_time: 42.457419  Lock_time: 0.000061 Rows_sent: 14035  Rows_examined: 14035
SET timestamp=1611197506;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mg_core_file_storage`;
# Time: 2021-01-21T02:52:13.972654Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 17397
# Query_time: 24.028741  Lock_time: 0.000075 Rows_sent: 13581026  Rows_examined: 13581026
SET timestamp=1611197533;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mg_log_url`;
# Time: 2021-01-21T02:52:56.953922Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 17397
# Query_time: 42.974997  Lock_time: 0.000050 Rows_sent: 13581026  Rows_examined: 13581026
SET timestamp=1611197576;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mg_log_url_info`;
# Time: 2021-01-21T02:53:29.854272Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 17397
# Query_time: 32.889769  Lock_time: 0.000062 Rows_sent: 11844480  Rows_examined: 11844480
SET timestamp=1611197609;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mg_log_visitor`;
# Time: 2021-01-21T02:54:02.815381Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 17397
# Query_time: 32.941569  Lock_time: 0.000072 Rows_sent: 11844481  Rows_examined: 11844481
SET timestamp=1611197642;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mg_log_visitor_info`;
# Time: 2021-01-21T06:00:33.640808Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_g1[orchidaf_g1] @ localhost []  Id: 20331
# Query_time: 15.917818  Lock_time: 0.000147 Rows_sent: 5915  Rows_examined: 34999055
use orchidaf_g1;
SET timestamp=1611208833;
SELECT `log_customer_main`.`log_id` FROM `mg_log_customer` AS `log_customer_main`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_log_customer` AS `log_customer` ON log_customer_main.customer_id = log_customer.customer_id AND log_customer_main.log_id < log_customer.log_id WHERE (log_customer.customer_id IS NULL) AND (log_customer_main.log_id < 8575);
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:01:15.414325Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_g1[orchidaf_g1] @ localhost []  Id: 21396
# Query_time: 56.789029  Lock_time: 0.000784 Rows_sent: 89  Rows_examined: 78045802
SET timestamp=1611212475;
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_core_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` ON url_rewrite.category_id=main_table.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND url_rewrite.store_id = 1 AND url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%'
 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_category_entity_int` AS `t1_is_active` ON main_table.entity_id=t1_is_active.entity_id AND t1_is_active.store_id=0
 LEFT JOIN `mg_catalog_category_entity_int` AS `t2_is_active` ON t1_is_active.entity_id = t2_is_active.entity_id AND t1_is_active.attribute_id = t2_is_active.attribute_id AND t2_is_active.store_id = 1 WHERE (main_table.path LIKE '1/2/%') AND (t1_is_active.attribute_id='42') AND ((IF(t2_is_active.value_id > 0, t2_is_active.value, t1_is_active.value))=1);
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:01:18.765262Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_g1[orchidaf_g1] @ localhost []  Id: 21396
# Query_time: 3.336039  Lock_time: 0.001113 Rows_sent: 910  Rows_examined: 688339
SET timestamp=1611212478;
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `mg_catalog_product_entity` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_product_website` AS `w` ON main_table.entity_id = w.product_id
 LEFT JOIN `mg_core_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` ON url_rewrite.product_id = main_table.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_system = 1 AND url_rewrite.category_id IS NULL AND url_rewrite.store_id = 1 AND url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'product/%'
 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t1_visibility` ON main_table.entity_id=t1_visibility.entity_id AND t1_visibility.store_id=0
 LEFT JOIN `mg_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t2_visibility` ON t1_visibility.entity_id = t2_visibility.entity_id AND t1_visibility.attribute_id = t2_visibility.attribute_id AND t2_visibility.store_id = 1
 INNER JOIN `mg_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t1_status` ON main_table.entity_id=t1_status.entity_id AND t1_status.store_id=0
 LEFT JOIN `mg_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t2_status` ON t1_status.entity_id = t2_status.entity_id AND t1_status.attribute_id = t2_status.attribute_id AND t2_status.store_id = 1 WHERE (w.website_id='1') AND (t1_visibility.attribute_id='102') AND ((IF(t2_visibility.value_id > 0, t2_visibility.value, t1_visibility.value)) IN(3, 2, 4)) AND (t1_status.attribute_id='96') AND ((IF(t2_status.value_id > 0, t2_status.value, t1_status.value)) IN(1));
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:02:39.921925Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id: 21421
# Query_time: 9.759513  Lock_time: 0.000145 Rows_sent: 51  Rows_examined: 11782865
use orchidaf_flower;
SET timestamp=1611212559;
SELECT `visitor_table`.`visitor_id` FROM `mg_log_visitor` AS `visitor_table`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_log_customer` AS `customer_table` ON visitor_table.visitor_id = customer_table.visitor_id AND customer_table.log_id IS NULL WHERE (visitor_table.last_visit_at < '2020-07-25 07:02:16') LIMIT 100;
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:02:51.136650Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id: 21421
# Query_time: 11.194526  Lock_time: 0.000168 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 11782764
SET timestamp=1611212571;
SELECT `visitor_table`.`visitor_id` FROM `mg_log_visitor` AS `visitor_table`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_log_customer` AS `customer_table` ON visitor_table.visitor_id = customer_table.visitor_id AND customer_table.log_id IS NULL WHERE (visitor_table.last_visit_at < '2020-07-25 07:02:16') LIMIT 100;
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:04:55.377500Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id: 21421
# Query_time: 121.071760  Lock_time: 0.000136 Rows_sent: 87  Rows_examined: 13511768
SET timestamp=1611212695;
SELECT `url_info_table`.`url_id` FROM `mg_log_url_info` AS `url_info_table`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_log_url` AS `url_table` ON url_info_table.url_id = url_table.url_id WHERE (url_table.url_id IS NULL) LIMIT 100;
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:07:50.817293Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id: 21421
# Query_time: 175.434851  Lock_time: 0.000154 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 13511594
SET timestamp=1611212870;
SELECT `url_info_table`.`url_id` FROM `mg_log_url_info` AS `url_info_table`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_log_url` AS `url_table` ON url_info_table.url_id = url_table.url_id WHERE (url_table.url_id IS NULL) LIMIT 100;
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:08:13.168514Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id: 21421
# Query_time: 21.982930  Lock_time: 0.000146 Rows_sent: 330  Rows_examined: 328916
SET timestamp=1611212893;
SELECT `event_table`.`event_id` FROM `mg_report_event` AS `event_table`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_log_visitor` AS `visitor_table` ON event_table.subject_id = visitor_table.visitor_id WHERE (visitor_table.visitor_id IS NULL) AND (event_table.subtype = 1) LIMIT 1000;
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:08:28.824506Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id: 21421
# Query_time: 15.592551  Lock_time: 0.000444 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 328256
SET timestamp=1611212908;
SELECT `event_table`.`event_id` FROM `mg_report_event` AS `event_table`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_log_visitor` AS `visitor_table` ON event_table.subject_id = visitor_table.visitor_id WHERE (visitor_table.visitor_id IS NULL) AND (event_table.subtype = 1) LIMIT 1000;
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:08:43.027030Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id: 21421
# Query_time: 13.761943  Lock_time: 0.000154 Rows_sent: 94  Rows_examined: 281692
SET timestamp=1611212923;
SELECT `main_table`.`index_id` FROM `mg_report_viewed_product_index` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_log_visitor` AS `visitor_table` ON main_table.visitor_id = visitor_table.visitor_id WHERE (main_table.visitor_id > 0) AND (visitor_table.visitor_id IS NULL) LIMIT 100;
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:08:57.321430Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id: 21421
# Query_time: 14.277155  Lock_time: 0.000203 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 281504
SET timestamp=1611212937;
SELECT `main_table`.`index_id` FROM `mg_report_viewed_product_index` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `mg_log_visitor` AS `visitor_table` ON main_table.visitor_id = visitor_table.visitor_id WHERE (main_table.visitor_id > 0) AND (visitor_table.visitor_id IS NULL) LIMIT 100;
# Time: 2021-01-21T07:14:30.162385Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id: 21642
# Query_time: 4.467782  Lock_time: 0.000102 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 47314
SET timestamp=1611213270;
DELETE FROM `mg_core_session` WHERE (session_expires < 1611213265);
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.7.33-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 2021-01-21T12:11:43.793219Z
# User@Host: orchidaf_flower[orchidaf_flower] @ localhost []  Id:    96
# Query_time: 4.863873  Lock_time: 0.000115 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 47259
use orchidaf_flower;
SET timestamp=1611231103;
DELETE FROM `mg_core_session` WHERE (session_expires < 1611231098);
```

Comment: Allysin, The gist.github 8464261 you used is to find products with no 'images'.  A very different problem than products with no SKU.  Still looking for you.

Comment: Allysin, Is your SLOW QUERY Log turned on?  Please post last 400 lines of your Slow Query Log from your 2.4.1 instance.

Comment: Please post the query you are using trying to find products with NO SKUs.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck Thank you for helping. I am not sure about the SLOW QUERY Log. I will ask my hosting company to enable it. I was able to identify the few products which have no SKUs by looking into the Admin of the older Magento (1.9.4). How can I edit them in phpMyAdmin of the new Magento 2.4.1 in order to add the SKUs to them?

Comment: I am changing the SKUs now in the database in the catalog_product_entity table.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck The issue with the Error message is fixed now. I fixed it by going to the catalog_product_entity table in the database, ordering it so that the products with no SKU would come up first and then editing those products right in the database (adding SKU numbers). The Error is gone but everything is still very slow in the Admin panel - is this what the SLOW QUERY Log could help with?

Comment: Allysin, Yes, after the Slow Query Log is available, analysis will likely allow us to determine where indexes would improve response time. Please post the log to pastebin.com and share the link.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck I just took the output for today and it seemed to fit as an add-on to my original post (above). I'm just not sure if this includes both of our Magento's as we run the older version still (1.9.4.0) which we are migrating to Magento 2.4.1 and that is what is very very slow.

Comment: @Allysin can you please provide the exception / system logs from the var folder of your magento instance so a better understanding of the issue can be found.

Comment: @Allysin Thanks for your Slow Query Log will check it soon.  Is this SQLog from your Magento 2.4.1 system? View Profile, Network profile for contact information and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: @Allysin There are several SELECT * in the slow query log.  Please pick out two that you would like me to look at that have some form of WHERE for research.  Give me the Query_time: nnnnnn   number of seconds so I can analyze the following query.  Have a GREAT Safe weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running query: update catalog_product_entity set sku = entity_id where sku is null

Please let me know if that helps!